PHP Update & Cloud Linux Hardening
I am using cpanel with a wordpress theme, that is showing the PHP as out of date, when I go to update it, cloud linux says it is hardened and there is nothing to do. The error shows in the panel and it seems I cant activate the Ultimate member plug in as the wordpress version is out of date and wont update due to the PHP error.
The activation button on the Ultimate member plug in returns the following error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in /home/dstvqbja/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/includes/admin/core/class-admin-settings.php on line 3392
Please help
see above - am receiving the errors and have tried checking the install code for the error but cant seem to access line 3392

"that is showing the PHP as out of date" - what does it show, exactly?  Edit your question, copy paste the text (not screenshot) of what you are seeing. "when I go to update it - how did you try to update it, exactly?  If you typed some commands on the console, edit your question and add those commands here.  If you did something through the Cpanel admin, describe what you did.  "cloud linux says it is hardened and there is nothing to do" - what does this mean?  What did it say, exactly? Edit your question, add any messages you saw (text, not screenshots).

We can't fix vague problems in unseen code, as described above you'll need to be a lot more specific. See [ask]
